# is it possible to force a program to use my reverse proxy?

Tags: c#, reverse-proxy, fiddler

I'm trying to modify HTTPS requests of a certain program using Fiddler the problem is that the requests the program sends don't show up in Fiddler because the program uses its own proxy instead of using the system proxy, the requests still show up in Wireshark but I can't modify or read them using Wireshark

Comment: Operating system you use?

Comment: What proxy does the program use?

Comment: I'm on windows 10, also 
the code the program uses probably looks something like "HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = new WebProxy();" or HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy = null;"

Comment: Is the proxy used by the program accesses by it's IP or by a DNS name (are there DNS requests in Wireshark?). If it uses DNS you could redirect data to Fiddler by creating an appropriate entry in the `hosts` file and change Fiddler's proxy port to the port number used by the other proxy.

Comment: unfortunately not, the protocol for all of the requests are "TCP" and "TLSv1.3" @Robert

Comment: That is not what I was asking for. How is the proxy server addressed? By IP address or by DNS-name and is the proxy server (only the server not the site that is accessed) connection a TLS connection or a plaintext connection (CONNECT request is visible unencrypted). You need Wireshark to answer those questions.

Comment: are you talking about this? [https://imgur.com/i2chl8B](https://imgur.com/i2chl8B) if not then I have no clue how to get the information you're asking for @Robert

Comment: I don't think that the program uses an own proxy, that looks like a regular HTTPS call but the program may ignore the system proxy configuration. You may be able to intercept the traffic using mitmproxy in transparent proxy mode. But that requires a Linux system and some iptable rules for interception.